# How to read an Android CrashLog

Tags: javascript, java, cordova, nullpointerexception, cordova-plugins

We use a Cordova app and have a plugin for google maps.

Using AWS lambda we set up a service to send back a cropped user avatar for the map. It used to work, but now everytime we visit the map the app is crashing (the map shows momentarily but once the avatar tries to plot it crashes). I have attached 5 groups of logcat crashlogs here.

I have individually tried to Google each line by line, but not helping be understand the cause. Is the 'caused by' line in each crash, the reason OF the crash? Or is it higher up? I am not sure how to read these. Am I initially told of the crash (first cpl lines) then further down explained the reasoning?

Thanks so much we are perplexed on this issue. And no the img is not vector and worked a few weeks ago.

```
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mapfindme.mapfindme, PID: 27372
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig()' on a null object reference
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.addBitmapToMemoryCache(AsyncLoadImage.java:80)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImage.java:557)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImage.java:27)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
01-20 10:23:42.817 27372 27399 E AndroidRuntime: ... 4 more
01-20 10:23:42.906 698 698 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/27372/oom_score_adj; errno=22
01-20 10:23:43.055 698 698 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/27433/oom_score_adj; errno=22
01-20 10:23:43.362 984 1126 E libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99018 pid 27433: Permission denied
01-20 10:23:43.610 984 1126 E libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99017 pid 26569: Permission denied

01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mapfindme.mapfindme, PID: 29625
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig()' on a null object reference
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.addBitmapToMemoryCache(AsyncLoadImage.java:80)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImage.java:557)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImage.java:27)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
01-20 10:31:51.041 29625 29704 E AndroidRuntime: ... 4 more
01-20 10:31:53.532 984 1126 E libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99020 pid 29728: Permission denied
01-20 10:31:55.150 984 3672 E InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{c1a30ae u0 Application Error: com.mapfindme.mapfindme} has
no registered input channel
01-20 10:31:55.167 984 3026 E InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{c1a30ae u0 Application Error: com.mapfindme.mapfindme} has
no registered input channel
01-20 10:32:01.523 29977 29977 E mapFindme.mapfindme: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
01-20 10:32:03.073 652 30023 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (105, /0)
01-20 10:32:03.136 652 30025 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (105, /0)
01-20 10:32:03.812 652 30041 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (105, /0)
01-20 10:32:05.509 698 698 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/28242/oom_score_adj; errno=22

01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mapfindme.mapfindme, PID: 30362
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig()' on a null object reference
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.addBitmapToMemoryCache(AsyncLoadImage.java:80)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImage.java:557)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImage.java:27)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
01-20 10:33:07.148 30362 30389 E AndroidRuntime: ... 4 more
01-20 10:33:07.996 698 698 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/28644/oom_score_adj; errno=22
01-20 10:33:08.018 652 30690 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (105, /0)
01-20 10:33:09.716 984 1126 E libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99022 pid 30412: Permission denied

01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mapfindme.mapfindme, PID: 30750
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig()' on a null object reference
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.addBitmapToMemoryCache(AsyncLoadImage.java:80)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImage.java:557)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImage.java:27)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
01-20 10:33:57.625 30750 30778 E AndroidRuntime: ... 4 more
01-20 10:33:58.948 652 31026 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (105, /0)
01-20 10:34:00.112 984 1126 E libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99023 pid 30801: Permission denied

01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mapfindme.mapfindme, PID: 2155
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig()' on a null object reference
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.addBitmapToMemoryCache(AsyncLoadImage.java:80)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImage.java:557)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at plugin.google.maps.AsyncLoadImage.doInBackground(AsyncLoadImage.java:27)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
01-20 10:39:55.545 2155 2354 E AndroidRuntime: ... 4 more
01-20 10:39:55.584 698 698 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/2155/oom_score_adj; errno=22
01-20 10:39:55.828 984 1126 E libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99034 pid 2245: Permission denied`
```

Comment: Yeah I would say this is your problem "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap$Config android.graphics.Bitmap.getConfig()' on a null object reference"

Comment: gforce301 is that due to the 'caused by'? Is everything above it mute?

Comment: I wouldn't say that exactly but it's any/all of those `NullPointerException`. Those are the lines you need to look at.